# Loop over columns to compare two columns at a time in a dataframe and add one summary column based on each comparison result

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, matching, data-comparison

[df1.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JM32n.png)

[df2.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYehv.png)

After executing the code below,

> df1.merge(df2, on=['Customer_id'], indicator='Status', how='outer')

I get,

[df3.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4W4p.png)

Now I want to compare whether all elements in Name_x is equal to Name_y or not, similarly for other columns as well. What i am doing is comparing it individually. Here is my code:

> df3.assign(Status1=df3.Name_x == df3.Name_y)
>
> df3.assign(Status2=df3.Age_x == df3.Age_y)

and so on

After doing above i get,

[df4.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PlEj.png)

Can i write **for loop** so that i do not have to write the code

> df3.assign()

individually for comparing every two columns?

and most importantly my **final status** column should look like this,

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emJZF.png)

what i am doing is thinking to write **if elif** like this:

> def f(row):
>
> ```
> if row['Status1'] == 'True' and row['Status2'] == 'False':
>     val = 'Matching for column {Name}'
> elif row['Status1'] == 'False' and row['Status1'] == 'True':
>     val = 'Matching for column {Age}
> elif row['Status1'] == 'False' and row['Status1'] == 'False':
>     val = 'Not Matching at all' #and so on...
> return val
> ```

This is okay if one want to write **if elif**  only on two columns **Status1 and Status2** and becomes lengthy if one want to write **if elif** on more than 2 columns. Can i get the desired output in few lines of code if i have column **Status3** also?

Comment: You seem to be asking us to code your application for you, rather than asking a specific programming question.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example of your issue. We're not here to do your homework assignments. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pandas.merge

Read both csv into pandas

```
df1=pd.Dataframe.from_csv('file')
df2=pd.Dataframe.from_csv('file2')
```

then Merge using an "outer" join

```
df3=pd.merge(df1,df2,on=[key1,key2 etc], how="outer", indicator=True)
```

At this point you should be 90% done